# Tasks should show up only if the user has been assigned it

Tags: odoo

I only want the person who I have assigned the task to see the task in the project module. I don't want other users of the project to see this persons tasks.

However currently any user who has user access rights can see all the tasks even if they were not assigned it.

Is there a work around this ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

OpenERP/Odoo has two kinds of security restrictions that can be assigned to a user group:

- [**Access Rights**](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/security.html#access-control) are CRUD yes/no flags (similar to Unix FS permissions), and allow **per-model** access control. They state whether members of this group may perform a Create, Read, Update, and Delete operation on any document of a certain document model (e.g. a project task). The default policy is DENY, so by default any operation will be refused if the user does not explicitly have the right to perform it via one of her groups' access rights.
- [**Record Rules**](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/security.html#record-rules) are filters applied on CRUD operations, and allow **per-document** access-control, once access right are already granted. Users will only be able to perform an operation on a given document if the document matches at least one of the record rules. The default policy is ALLOW, so if no rule exists for a given model, all documents of that model may be accessed by users who have the necessary access rights.

Both Access Rights and Record Rules may also be defined globally without assigning them to a specific group, in which case they apply to everyone. There is one pitfall for Record Rules: global rules may NOT be relaxed by other rules (on purpose!), so use with care.

In your case it looks like you should define one extra Record Rule on the Project User group that explicitly restricts access on Project Tasks to your own tasks (and presumably those that are not assigned yet). You need to create a new entry in the Security Rules menu with these parameters:

- object/model: `project.task`
- name: `See own tasks only`
- domain: `['|',('user_id','=',False),('user_id','=',user.id)]`

  - (means: your own tasks and unassigned ones)
- apply for read: `[x]`
- apply for write: `[x]`
- apply for create: `[x]`
- apply for delete: `[x]`
- groups: `Project / User`

The `domain` of a record rule is a standard OpenERP/Odoo domain that is evaluated on the records on which you are trying to perform the operation, and can refer to a `user` variable that contains the current user's data (technically, a `browse_record` on the current user). [The documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/orm.html#reference-orm-domains) has a description of `domain`.

If you want to allow special users (e.g. Project Managers) to view all tasks in the system, you can relax this rule for them by adding another rule to the Project Manager group which allows access to all tasks. There is a special "domain filter" that means "ALLOW ALL" and is useful to relax another stricter rule: `[(1,'=',1)]`.

**Note 1**: Have a look at the existing Record Rules to see what they're doing first, and be sure to read the explanations on the Record Rule form when you are adding yours. One important thing to keep in mind is that group-specific rules are combined with an `OR` operator. So if you add the rule I described above, you may not see any restriction effect because other group-specific rules are still giving access. You may have to disable them, edit them, or change the user group they apply to, to get the exact effect you want.

**Note 2**: Remember that if you do something wrong with Access Rights and Record Rules, you can always fix the mess with the `admin` account, as these security restrictions do not apply to the `admin` (similarly to the `root` user on Unix).

Comment: Nice answer, Olivier, I didn't know about record rules. I'm glad to see you're becoming a regular contributor here.

Comment: thank u for the detailed answer. this worked for me [('user_id','=',user.id)]

Comment: see here for record rules in XML : http://help.openerp.com/question/12667/setting-up-rules-access-right-in-xmlcsv-files/

Comment: I found no object with name `project.task` ?

Comment: I tried this in Odoo 11 but I didn't get a results. A user who is a follower of a project can view all the tasks of that project.

Comment: @cataclysmic: indeed you always need to consider existing rules that may need to be modified or deactivated to achieve the desired result, as you describe in your answer. I added a note to warn about that in mine :)

Comment: @odony: Great. I guess the naming conventions for the rules change across odoo versions. So my answer is only valid for Odoo 11.
I further realized that this rule is very strict. It also blocks viewing for users as followers and also blocks them from seeing assigned activities on the blocked tasks.
It would be better to have a rule that still permits that. I didn't figure out how, yet. I guess another approach would be to do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45006235/disable-automatic-addition-of-partner-as-follower-in-odoo-10 and block all non-followers.

Answer (score 2):

Note: In OpenERP 7 you have to modify or disable the defualt rule called

> Project/Task: employees: public, portal, employee or following or
>   assigned

To get your rule working.

Comment: how to modify this such that project-managers should be able to see all but others should be able to see only their tasks ?

Comment: I couldn't find this rule under Odoo v11. Do you have any idea where it is on v11? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new security rule, select Object as "**project.task**" ,give domain filter as **[("user_id","=",user.id)]**. No need to add any groups, so that it will be global. Thats it!

Answer (score 1):

My problem was a bit more complex. I wanted to have users who can only their assigned tasks and some who can see the rest, too.

In Odoo 11 I found that the standard project user inherits `Employees \ Employee` which in turn has the rule `Project/Task: employees: follow required for follower-only projects` which let users see the other tasks.

What I did:

1. create a new group -> duplicate of `Project / Users`
2. implemented the rule from **odony**'s answer -> `['|',('user_id','=',False),('user_id','=',user.id)]`
3. removed the record rule `Project/Task: employees: follow required for follower-only projects` from `Employees / Employee` and added it to `Project / Users`

Now I can decide who is a *project user*, who can see all tasks of a project, and who is a *worker*, who only gets to see tasks assigned to them.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed by @user1534055 in openERP 7, it's a bit-different.

Find the rule named `Project/Task: employees: public, portal, employee or following or assigned`

[image: Find the associated record rule]

Edit it and remove `('project_id.privacy_visibility', 'in', ['public', 'portal', 'employees']),
                                                '&',` from the rule definition and hit Save.

After this tasks will be visible to only those who've been assigned.