# different permissions based on workflow state

Tags: permissions, workflow, odoo

I need to set up different permission on an object based on its workflow state. For instance, 'manager group' can edit the object only if state=draft but 'super manager group' can edit it also if state=validated.

It seems that's not possible using `ir.model.access` and I'm evaluating if it could be done using `ir.rule`. It seems not...

Is there a `official` way to get this or do I need to implement this feature (maybe by adding a condition into ir.model.access machinery).

Comment: do u want to show this in your own model or in the existing model like sale.order, purchase.order etc?? In which openerp version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible by default with `ir.model.access`, because this permission model is designed to act like simple Unix permission on CRUD operations, and it is statically defined, per-model and per-group.

You may be able to implement something like this using `ir.rule`, as it implements dynamic per-record access control based on field values. By having a set of rules defined only on the `write` and `unlink` operations and based on the `state` field, you will be able to prevent some groups from modifying records in certain states. By using the technique of an always-true rule `[(1,'=',1)]` you can then relax a non-global rule for users who have a "super-access" group. See also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945270/tasks-should-show-up-only-if-the-user-has-been-assigned-it/10947529#10947529).
This option will have important caveats however:

- Be careful not to make those rules apply for `read`, as it will make the records completely disappear, and generally wreak havoc in your processes
- The interface will not become read-only when the rule is in effect, and if you want to make the fields and buttons read-only you will have to find a way to specify this via `attrs` in a manner that depends on the user's groups. See also this [Launchpad question](https://answers.launchpad.net/openobject-server/+question/178779).
- the Save button in the UI will not be disabled
- The standard error reporting in case of `ir.rule` restriction is not very clear, so it will certainly confuse users (note: it's being improved for 7.0)

As you see, using `ir.rule` filters for this purpose is far from a perfect solution, and you will first need to find appropriate solutions for the above issues.

Ultimately, you might have an easier task of implementing your own logic for this, plugging a new mechanism in the ORM primitive API methods: `fields_view_get` (for making fields dynamically read-only based on the user groups) and the CRUD methods (for actually restricting the operations)

Comment: yep, that's my conclusion as well and that's why I said "I'm evaluating if it could be done using ir.rule. *It seems not...*" :) A possible solution would be ir.rule + web client hacking for showing edit/delete/duplicate buttons accordingly, hoping that you are not going to rewrite this on v7.0 :P anyway, tnx for your exhaustive answer.

Comment: There will be quite a few evolutions in the web client API in 7.0, so your mileage may vary depending on which parts you extend. The API design will not change much, but specific areas will be improved in ways that will not always be backwards-compatible. BTW the 7.0 API will probably contain extra data in the result of `fields_view_get()` to let the client know what buttons to display, based on user access rights on that model. You might want to watch trunk for this (not done yet), in case you can make your own implementation use the same naming conventions.

Comment: yes, fields_view_get on_loaded, that's where I'm trying to plug in.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way instead of hacking web-client.
You can always have 2 views for the same Object .

1. For manager group.
2. For super manager group.

In manager group you can use attrs = {'readonly': [('state', '!=', 'draft')]}

or any condition as you needed.

And in the same way in super manager group, you can put his condition for fields.

Answer (score 0):

I have this feature working on a production environment, using just Record Rules: in Project Issues, "basic users" can create and cancel issues, but can't open or close them.
Despite the GUI limitations mentioned by @odony, it works perfectly.

These are the Record Rules used:[image]:

There is a special case that needs attention: changing from a read-write State to a read-only State:

In the action's method, if the the State is changed after other `write` operations, the user will be able to change the State; but if there are some `write` operations after the State update, the user will not be able to change State.

In my example, the Project Issue method to Open an issue is `case_open()`. It first changes State and then does additional changes, like settting Open Date, User and Message history. Because of this, basic users can't Open issues. If you want them to be able to do so, `case_open()` must be overridden so that it changes State after all other `write` operations are done.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar requirement...
My requirement was to make a char field(say "test_123") readonly in the sale.order if the user comes under the group "sale user" otherwise editable for the group "Sale Manager".
That is, if the sale order is in draft state then anyone can edit, but it the sale order is confirmed then this field "test_123" is only editable for "Sale Manger"

What I did is I added a functional field (is_group_manager) which returns True if the user comes under the group "sale manager" and the state is not "draft" otherwise false.
Then in the xml view I added the field "test_123" with attribute `attrs="{'readonly':[('is_group_manager','=',0)]}"`
for example

```
<field name="is_group_manager" invisible="1"/>
<field name="test_123" attrs="{'readonly':[('is_group_manager','=',0)]}"/>
```

This will work only in openerp v6.0. Maybe this will be helpful for you. :)