# How can I hide Create button from tree view in a specific object. As this object has all the fields readonly

Tags: javascript, jquery, odoo

How can I hide Create button from tree view in a specific object? As this object has all the fields readonly.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It depends on which OpenERP version you are working, please mention it if you'd like more specific answers. If you're asking this question you're probably not using 7.0 yet, but it might be useful to know nevertheless.

### OpenERP 7.0

As of OpenERP 7.0 the system will automatically do this for you for each of the following possible actions: *create, edit, delete*: if the current user has no access (based on the Access Rights configuration) the corresponding flag will be added to the root node of the view definition, effectively hiding the option in the UI.
These flags correspond respectively to the following access rights: `create`, `write`, `unlink`.

As user1576199 mentioned, this flag could also be set manually in your view definition, but that should only be required when the access rights do not correspond to the options you want to show. You could do it in this manner, in any combination:

```
<tree create="false" delete="false">
....
</tree>
or
<kanban create="false" edit="false">
....
</kanban>
etc..
```

### OpenERP 6.1 and earlier

There is no option to hide these buttons, so you'll need to customize the OpenERP client(s) if you want to specifically achieve that. simahawk's answer gave you some starting points for the web client 6.1, which is probably what you want to customize.

Comment: Thanks  odony,it is exactly what i needed,I had a similar problem but with this solution that problem is not same.
the problem is I need to hide "Print" button from an object on which reports exists for print but they are printed using wizard from a different button on form. I want to hide the global print button from a particular object.

Comment: @StackUP: Glad to help. If the answer suits you, the process on StackOverflow is to mark it as accepted :-) As for the visibility of items in the _Print_ menu, it is driven by action bindings in the 'ir.tables' values. Look for entries with `model='<your_model>' AND key2='client_print_multi'`. Those bindings are mostly established by the ``<act_window>`` XML element in module data files.

Comment: @odony: thanks a lott. Where can click on accepted?
If you are saying about mark "yes" on "Was this post useful to you?"
So I already did it. If something else please let me know.

Comment: @odony : i was not asking visibility of items under print menu, I want to remove standard "Print" button from object "A" where I am not printing any thing using print button, but it is available here because i made some pdf reports using wizard on this object. and printing them by clicking on different button.

Comment: @StackUP: to accept an answer simply click on the check mark icon under the answer score on the left. The whole process is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: @StackUP: Concerning the Print menu I understand what you want to do, and you should try what I suggested. If you hide all the reports from the Print menu it will disappear naturally. And you don't need the entries in `ir.values` to be able to start your print wizards with a button on the form view, so it's fine. All you have to do is to get rid of the unnecessary entries in `ir.values`. The easiest way in your module is to remove the `src_model` attribute from the `<act_window>` XML tag you use to declare your records. Do it then try to create a new database to test, it should work.

Comment: @odony: thank you but what about "Export" button which appears under "More"? How it can be removed from a particular object.

Comment: Anyone can suggest solution for openERP 9 ?

Answer (score 0):

there's no built-in feature for this. edit/delete/etc buttons are always in place even if you do not have access to the actions behind them, there's [no check on permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10994216/different-permissions-based-on-workflow-state)

anyway, you can do your javascript hack and do something like $('button.oe_form_button_edit').hide() or whatever. [here are some tips](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11950556/647924) on how to start developing web addons.

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this on tree view

```
<tree string="String" create="false">
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this on v6 is to hide it with CSS (which is easier than @simahawk's suggestion). You can do this by adding CSS to your form view xml, which contains the tree. Eg:

```
<html>
  <style>
    .openerp button.oe_form_button_edit { display:none }
  </style>
</html>
<tree ...
```

You can do the same for the delete and edit buttons as needed.

Bit of a hack... I like the v7 functionality - can't wait to upgrade :)

Comment: Interesting solution @timothy this works in form view but how to embed <html> in tree view. It throws an error.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that you need to add the html tag to the form view that contains the tree.

Comment: But that will not hide from tree view.

Comment: @StackUP you wont be able to use this trick on a tree "page". The alternative in that scenario is to hardcode the css into the base.css style (not a great idea).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this solution is correct or not, but I try to put this code below in a javascript in core, and it works actually.

```
openerp.web.ListView.include({

    start: function() {
        var self = this;
        var ret = this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        var res_model = this.dataset.model;
        if ($.inArray(res_model, MODELS_TO_HIDE) != -1) {
            self.options.addable = false; /* for create button */
            self.options.deletable= false; /* for delete button */
        };
        return ret;
    },
});
```

or u can refer to this link:
https://github.com/kdeldycke/kevin-deldycke-blog/blob/master/content/posts/openerp-61-web-javascript-hacks-hide-buttons.md