# records access - per record acess rules

Tags: odoo

I'm trying to figure out what would be the best way to **only** allow the records author (`create_uid`) to `write`, `unlink` a record.

According to the source below it seems to be doable with Records rules.

[Allowing each manager to see only the project he creates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11255743/allowing-each-manager-to-see-only-the-project-he-creates/11256226#11256226)

I could only find example on only how to only show the records of the records author.

Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 0):

Record rules can be applied for filtering data and to provide rule specific access.  Based on this rules you can configure rights for `write` and `delete`.

Comment: Can you please provide an example?