# OpenERP: Project Manager's Manager should be able to see all the Project's and Task's assigned to his Sub Ordinate

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I have started doing OpenERP customization recently.
Previously all the managers we able to see all the Projects and Tasks in the company.
Now I have written a Record rule so that Project Managers will be able to see only those Projects which are assigned to him based upon this.

[Allowing each manager to see only the project he creates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11255743/allowing-each-manager-to-see-only-the-project-he-creates)

Now for Example, I have a Project Manager "M1", say he is assigned with a project "ABC".
I have an other Project Manger "M2" assigned with a Project "XYZ".
Project Manger "M2" is the Manager of "M1".
(In Human Resource Module In the Employee menu you have a Manager Picklist where we are going to assign the manger for that Employee).
Now M1 should be able to see only "ABC" project and M2 should be able to see "ABC" and also "ZYZ" project. How should I write a record rule to get this hierarchy in the Project Managers.

Please Help me out.