# Disable automatic addition of partner as follower in Odoo 10

Tags: python, odoo-10

How can I stop automatic addition of partners as followers in Odoo 10. Whenever I create a new quotation or opportunity, the partner is automatically added to the followers list and an email notification is send to the partner which I don't want.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using simple method.

Ex:

```
class sale_order(models.Model):
    _inherit="sale.order"

    @api.model
    def create(self,vals):
        res=super(sale_order,self.with_context('mail_create_nosubscribe':True)).create(vals)
        return res
```

If you pass **mail_create_nosubscribe True** in  the context, system will not add **default followers in the message**.

> **Odoo is supporting mainly three type of keyword in the mail message context,using that you can enable/disable processes model wise.**

**1.tracking_disable :** At create and write, perform no MailThread features (auto subscription, tracking, post, ...)

**2.mail_create_nosubscribe :** At create or message_post, do not subscribe
       uid to the record thread

**3.mail_create_nolog :** At create, do not log the automatic '
       created' message

> You need to just pass value in the context, system will disable
>   above features.

This may help you.

Comment: syntax error. the mail_create_nosubscribe: True needs to be in {}

Answer (score 3):

Not enough reputation to post this as a comment, so it had to be an answer, sorry for that.

You answer set me well on my way, I changed the code a little bit to make it work for me.

```
class sale_order(models.Model):
    _inherit="sale.order"
    @api.model
        def create(self, vals):    
            res = super(sale_order, self.with_context(mail_create_nosubscribe=True)).create(vals)
```

In addition, I noticed that the partner was still being added upon order confirmation. 
I resolved that with the following code:

```
@api.multi
    def action_confirm(self):

        return_value = super(sale_order, self.with_context(mail_create_nosubscribe=True)).action_confirm()

        for follower in self['message_follower_ids']:
            follower.unlink()

        return return_value
```